# Record not showing even the record exist in query using PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a query to fetch a record using unique `SAPID` and `CandidateID` but the record is not getting fetched.

But for the same SAPID and candidateId record exist. Here is my query below

```
SELECT VT.*,VTS.STATUS_NAME
        FROM TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT 
        LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_STATUS_MST VTS ON VT.STATUS_ID = VTS.STATUS_ID
        WHERE VT.SAP_ID = 'I-KA-CTPR-ENB-9016'
        AND VT.CANDIDATE_ID = 'C3';
```

Please suggest where I am wrong

**update**

```
SELECT ENB.SAP_ID AS SAP_ID,CAND.CANDIDATEID AS CANDIDATE_ID,ENB.R4G_STATE AS STATE,ENB.SITE_TYPE AS SITETYPE,CAND.SITENAME AS SITENAME,
CAND.STATUS AS CANDIDATESTATUS ,ENB.SITEID AS SITEID,ENB.PRIORITY_SITE AS PRIORITYSITE,ENB.CIRCLE AS CIRCLE,
DECODE (VTS.STATUS_NAME,null, 'Fill Vendor Survey form', VTS.STATUS_NAME) AS VSATSTATUS,
ENB.LATITUDE, ENB.LONGITUDE, VTS.STATUS_ID
FROM R4G_OSP.ENODEB ENB
INNER JOIN R4G_OSP.CANDIDATE CAND ON ENB.SAP_ID = CAND.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT ON ENB.SAP_ID = VT.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_STATUS_MST VTS ON VT.STATUS_ID = VTS.STATUS_ID
WHERE ENB.SCOPE = 'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
AND ENB.SITEBACKHAUL = 'MW'
AND CAND.STATUS = 'Fill Vendor Survey Form'
AND (VT.STATUS_ID IS NULL OR VT.STATUS_ID IN (2,4))
AND ENB.SAP_ID = 'I-KA-CTPR-ENB-9016'
AND CAND.CANDIDATEID = 'C3';
```

Comment: What is a result of this query; `SELECT * FROM TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL WHERE SAP_ID = 'I-KA-CTPR-ENB-9016' AND CANDIDATE_ID = 'C3'` ?

Comment: @krokodilko: NO records is coming.. but it is their

Comment: How can you say it is there?

Comment: @etsa: because it is coming from somewhere else. I will update the question

Comment: What do you mean with "it is coming from somewhere else"?  You can say "it should be there", but not "it is there"

Comment: So, there is no any record that meet these two conditions. Maybe there is some space appended to some field or so ? Start with `SELECT * FROM TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL WHERE CANDIDATE_ID = 'C3'` and examine carrefully the result.

Comment: @krokodilko: I am joining the table and bringing the records on the basis of `sap_id` and `candidate_id` which is not fetching the record gfor me

Comment: @etsa: yes u got it right now. its present their but not in `TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL` but in my first query from question i want it their too

Comment: What do you mean "I want it there too"?  Change your query and add the two tables missing, or add an insert in the DETAIL table

Comment: @etsa: as per my logic i want the data for that sap_id in my query which i made but it is not coming. may be my query is wrong

Comment: @etsa:please come here on chat, i will explan u https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148588/oracle

Comment: @etsa: can u help me with the query how to join to get those records on the basis of sap_id and candidate_id ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have the query: I derived it from your second query:

```
SELECT ENB.SAP_ID AS SAP_ID
    ,CAND.CANDIDATEID AS CANDIDATE_ID
     ,VT.*
     ,VTS.STATUS_NAME
FROM R4G_OSP.ENODEB ENB
INNER JOIN R4G_OSP.CANDIDATE CAND ON ENB.SAP_ID = CAND.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT ON ENB.SAP_ID = VT.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_STATUS_MST VTS ON VT.STATUS_ID = VTS.STATUS_ID
WHERE ENB.SCOPE = 'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
    AND ENB.SITEBACKHAUL = 'MW'
    AND CAND.STATUS = 'Fill Vendor Survey Form'
    AND (VT.STATUS_ID IS NULL
        OR VT.STATUS_ID IN (2, 4)
        )
    AND ENB.SAP_ID = 'I-KA-CTPR-ENB-9016'
    AND CAND.CANDIDATEID = 'C3';
```

Comment: so this one is the final one ??